# Having trouble getting started with SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I installed SonarQube and sonar-runner, and the web server seems to work just fine as I can browse it.  I tried to keep things as simple as I could, I put the "sonar-project.properties" file in my project's source folder and gave . as the sonar.sources path.  After doing so, the console output reported success and the web page listed my project and last analysis date, but when I went into the "Compare" tool to look at statistics it showed all items as blank, except for issues for which is displayed the number 0.

I edited the sonar-project.properties file to give the full path (instead of a relative current directory path of .) to my project's source code, replacing backslashes with forward slashes, and ran the sonar-runner command again from the command line while the working directory was the path of my source folder.  It again reported success and when I reloaded the web page, it gave an updated last analysis date, but again no issues were reported and the statistics were all blank.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, the Sonar log only reports the installation and starting of the Windows service, and it doesn't indicate any problems.  The StartNTService script starts the service without error, but the StartSonar script reports "jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]".  I don't know if that's relevant for the way I'm using SonarQube as a Windows service.  I'm using pretty much all default configuration except I edited the sonar-runner.properties file by un-commented these lines:

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
...
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

If anybody can help me figure out how to get this to work, I would greatly appreciate it.  I am running Windows XP Pro x64 SP2 and Java 1.7.0_51 (32 bit).  On my first attempt I did incorrectly use the 64 bit service install/launch scripts but when the console output indicated it didn't match the JVM architecture, I stopped and uninstalled the service and installed and launched the 32 bit service.

Edit:  I'm using Sonarqube version 4.2 and Sonar-runner version 2.3.

Comment: Using `.` as `sonar.sources` should definitely work. Which language(s) do you want to analyze? Did you make sure to have the plugins required for th(is|ese) language(s)?

Comment: My program is written in C, but some third party source files written in C++ are also used.  Perhaps I misunderstood things.  I see that a commercial C/C++ plugin is offered, I guess that means I won't be able to use SonarQube for free, and that the other plugins that bundle with it won't be able to operate either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SonarQube is packaged with the Java ecosystem (Java, Checkstyle, PMD), but for C/C++ you will have to install one of the plugins that support analysis of these languages.

There is a [commercial C++ plugin from SonarSource](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/cpp/) and a [free Community Plugin](https://github.com/wenns/sonar-cxx).

Comment: Thank you.  I downloaded the latest version of the community cxx plugin (0.9), stopped the Sonar service, put the plugin file (sonar-cxx-plugin-0.9.jar) in the extensions\plugins directory of my SonarQube installation, started the service, went to the updatecenter URL, logged in with the default admin account, verified "C++ (Community) [cxx] 0.9" was listed as an installed plugin, ran sonar-runner and saw it mention downloading and installing the cxx plugin, but when it finished, the SonarQube web page still behaved the same (all stats blank, 0 issues detected).  Anything else I missed?

Comment: After some more research I found I had to add "sonar.language=c++" to the sonar-project.properties file, and after doing so, launching sonar-runner again seemed to work, as it now gives statistics for the project.  Another page I saw indicated I'd have to specify the sonar.language as "cxx" instead of "c++", but it seemed to work anyway.  Is there anything left for me to set up?

Comment: It says there are 0 issues..  I may already be using several static code analysis programs, but I'm still skeptical about 0 issues found.  Short of intentionally introducing bugs to see if they get flagged, is there something else I could do to validate the results?